# My bluetooth headset is sizzle and no sound, I use 12.10

Tags: bluetooth, headset

I use blueman and bluez, sometimes no sound, sometimes the headset is sizzle...

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

The computer may not be choosing the right hardware to play.

Open the Sound settings (open your Dash and type *sound*). Go to the *Output* tab. You should see more than one option.

[image: Sound settings — Output]

Click the one that references your Bluetooth headphones. (You may have to double-click it.) Adjust the sounds as required. You can also use the <kbd>Test Sound</kbd> button.

Comment: [Image]:https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/VVYU6iCce1eEpzRguOh5htMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

I select the headset and use the test button, but I have got the same problem...

Comment: If i change the sound card to the headset and i play music or any sound, the headset is sizzle, or no sound.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know what to do from here. Have you tried the changing the Mód settings where it says `Telefon duplex (HSP/HSP)`?

Comment: No, i think it's correct. Mód settings means: the protocol when the headset is connected to the bluetooth stick. Teszt mean: test. When i push the test button, the headset is soundless, or sizzle.

Comment: Nevertheless, have you tried changing the Mód setting? You can easily change it back. I have sometimes been surprised by the settings that do work.

Comment: There is only two option: 1. Telefon duplex (HSP/HSP); 2. Off
I don't know what is the reason of the bad working.
One month ago, the headset was worked perfect to my pc.
I try to change "/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf", but no results.

Comment: Sorry, I have no further suggestions. You may want to try asking your question on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/).